Why cascade delete not working in PostgreSQL (SQLAlchemy)?
I'm trying to cascade-delete rows in table Product, but it is not working
seller_product = Table(
        "seller_product",
        Base.metadata,
        Column("start_id", Integer, nullable=False),
        Column("id_product", ForeignKey("product.ozon_id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False),
        Column("id_seller", ForeignKey("seller.ozon_id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False),
        Column("date_parse", DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    )


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"
    
    id: Mapped["int"] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ozon_id: Mapped["int"] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    title: Mapped["str"] = mapped_column()
    link: Mapped["str"] = mapped_column()
    seller_id: Mapped["int"] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("seller.ozon_id"))
    seller: Mapped["Seller"] = relationship(back_populates="products")

I tried removing different methods:
DELETE FROM seller_product CASCADE WHERE id_product = 4720943812

And like this:
DELETE FROM seller_product CASCADE WHERE start_id = 1

But the data from the product table is still not deleted. Why?

CASCADE is not valid SQL, never was. You have to tell your foreign keys how to handle cascading, not the DELETE.

Your thinking about the direction of cascades is backwards. Cascaded deletes will delete the related child records when a parent record is deleted. A many-to-many relationship is really a combination of two one-to-many relationships:

Notice that the association table "seller_product" is the child table of both parents, "seller" and "product". If the cascade deletes are correctly defined at the database level (i.e., on the table in the database, not just on the model in your Python code), deleting a "seller" row will remove the related rows in "seller_product" and deleting a "product" row will remove the related rows in "seller_product". However, deleting a row in "seller_product" will not delete the related rows in "seller" or "product".

Thanks for the clarifications. Is it somehow possible, when deleting a row in the seller_product table, to delete the associated row in the product table in one query?

DELETE FROM product WHERE ozon_id = 4720943812 - That will delete the row in "product" and cascade delete all rows in "seller_product" with that same "id_product", assuming that your database (table) configuration is correct.

Yes, it works. Is it possible to make sure that when you delete a row in the seller_product table, the row in the product table is deleted?

That doesn't make sense. Just because a  particular seller stops selling a certain product does not mean that the product ceases to exist.
